# Grounding Multiple Devices

Tags: power, motor, ground-loop

I am designing a motor controller with an Arudino, UBEC, and ESC. The Arduino will control Servo Motors and Brushless Motors. I want to make sure I understand how to hook up all the devices to avoid issues. I have been researching ground loops and want to make sure that I won't have any electrical issues. I have attached a schematic of what I believe is the correct hookup guide.

The black wires are ground, orange is power, and green is the signal wire.
[image]

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Also, please provide links to the datasheets for the battery, ESC, UBEC, motor, and servo. At the very least you need to label the various signals as to the **kind** of signal and label power lines with their expected voltage.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, I want to make sure I will not have a ground loop or any other issues in my schematic. The signal is a standard servo pulse, a PWM signal.

Comment: that is a block diagram or a very rough wiring diagram ... it is not a schematic

Comment: You appear to have attached a ground between the Arduino and Servo and nothing else.  It's not clear why you'd connect just these two components, or what you are actually grounding on either.  You also need to clarify which if any of the battery  connections or case will be grounded.  You need to clarify this for each device when you provide your schematic.  Do you know the difference between a ground and a return conductor?  You should also show your overcurrent protection devices.  It looks like your devices are probably either + polarity or irrelevant, but you should post the specs.